# How to tint a picture using Jython?

Tags: jython, tint, jes

In my class, we're using Jython (via JES) to do simple picture manipulations.  One of the questions requires us to write a function that takes a picture and a color as its input.  It tints the picture by taking the RGB values of the picture and averaging them with the RGB values of the input color, making a new RGB value set (so, r3 = (r1+r2) // 2, etc).  My question is, how do I extract the input color's RGB values such that they can be added and averaged?  What I have right now is essentially:

for pix in getPixels(newPic):

```
r = getRed(pix)
g = getGreen(pix)
b = getBlue(pix)
**colorR = getRed(color)
**colorG = getGreen(color)
**colorB = getBlue (color)
newR = (r + colorR) // 2
newG = (g + colorG) // 2
newB = (b + colorB) // 2
lumin = makeColor(newR, newG, newB)
setColor(pix, lumin)
```

The call would be something like:
*colorTint(pic, makeColor(0, 0, 0))*

The ** stuff is where my issue is.

Comment: Since this is a homework style question, I would maybe suggest you post a few ideas you have tried yourself so others can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Above is what I have thus far tried already